# Read values from ServiceStack.Redis Pipeline

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack.redis

How to read values from ServiceStack.Redis pipeline? I saw examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/RedisPipelineTests.cs), but I am not sure the code will work correctly if there are many QueueCommands at the same time(Let's say, 10000 for instance).

QueueCommand's callback seems to be an async operation. Each of the QueueCommand can have a callback. When Pipeline.Flush() is called, all QueueCommands will be sent to Redis Server in Pipeline Mode and when one of the QueueCommands is executed, its callback would be called.

My question is: When Pipeline.Flush() finishes, does the library guarantee that all callbacks are executed?

Here is the code ServiceStack.Redis on GitHub

```cs
    [Test]
    public void Can_call_single_operation_with_callback_3_Times_in_pipeline()
    {
        var results = new List<long>();
        Assert.That(Redis.GetValue(Key), Is.Null);
        using (var pipeline = Redis.CreatePipeline())
        {
            pipeline.QueueCommand(r => r.IncrementValue(Key), results.Add);
            pipeline.QueueCommand(r => r.IncrementValue(Key), results.Add);
            pipeline.QueueCommand(r => r.IncrementValue(Key), results.Add);
            //Can I assume that when Flush() finishes, 
            //all 3 callbacks (results.Add) would have finished?
            pipeline.Flush();
        }

        Assert.That(Redis.GetValue(Key), Is.EqualTo("3"));
        Assert.That(results, Is.EquivalentTo(new List<long> { 1, 2, 3 }));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some tests for Redis Pipeline API in:

- [RedisPipelineTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/RedisPipelineTests.cs)
- [RedisPipelineCommonTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/RedisPipelineCommonTests.cs)
- [RedisTypedPipelineTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/Generic/RedisTypedPipelineTests.cs)

Yes when you call `.Flush()` on a Redis Pipeline it [flushes all the buffered commands to redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/16cdeda7b54776d62fc11f0ec29cb615bb3e87b3/src/ServiceStack.Redis/Pipeline/RedisAllPurposePipeline.cs#L34) then executes all the queued callbacks.